# Will the execution time reduce if I make following changes to the loop?

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I want to run a loop for a large number (`N>10^4`).

Scenario 1:

```
for (i=1; i<=N; i++) {
    if(num%i==0)
    count++;
}
```

Scenario 2:

```
for(i=1; i<N; i=i+2) 
{
   if(num%i==0)
    count++;
}
for(i=2;i<N;i=i+2) 
{
   if(num%i==0)
    count++;
}
```

Will scenario 2 give a better execution time?

Comment: Most likely not. But why don't you give it a try and time the results?

Comment: (1) for performance questions you need to test and measure; (2) depends on what `//body does` - Question is both unclear and too broad.

Comment: It might give if both the loops use the same looping variable `i`. But in that case, it might miss some iterations.

Comment: Why do you think that this might reduce execution time?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel In scenario 2, if you are using same looping variable `i` outside the loop, `i` will have values 1 (while entering outer loop), 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ..., N (while entering inner loop). So, it won't execute all the iterations but it may have better execution time.

Comment: Why don'y you *measure*? Create an optimized build of your program, and run both loops with timers. Do that a few times, and get the average. You could also take a look at the generated code to see differences between them.

Comment: @KunalPuri well, yes, and I suspect that must be an error in the code, that's why I'm asking what OP thinks is supposed to be happening here. The question "which one is faster" kinda only makes sense if both options compute the same result which can't really be happening here unless `// body` has some magic properties that can be exploited…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I agree with your point. That's why I said *might*

Comment: When it comes to performance, there is one golden rule: ALWAYS measure.

Comment: actually i am using this for the first time so had some problems formatting the code.

Comment: if the //body were to contain a if statement??

Comment: @HrishikeshKamble If the code is small and [mcve], you may consider posting it.

Comment: Is first snippet supposed to be: `for (i=1; i<N; i++) {
    if (i % 2) {/*body1*/} else {/*body2*/}
}`?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes somewhat

Comment: 2 Scenarios are the same to me, must run the test to measure which one is better, but with Scenario 2 you modify it and do with multi-thread, that could be faster

Comment: From a different point of view, it's not clear why you may want to split the loop in two, and whoever goes to maintain/read your code next will wonder. Even if there was a performance gain (which, according to BattleTested, isn't there) it would be so small that it won't compare to the doubts it will cause to future readers of the code (including you 6 months down the line).

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca I was thinking in a wrong way..anyways realized my mistake. Thank u for your input. And yes the code is definetely confusing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have to test it with `chrono` standard library to get elapsed time for each scenario :**

Suppose `N` is :

```
#define     N   3000000000
```

***1st Scenario :***

```
void scenario1()
{
    int count = 0;
    int num = 10;

    for (int i=1; i<=N; i++) {
        if(num%i==0)
            count++;
    }
}
```

And ***2nd Scenario :***

```
void scenario2()
{
    int count = 0;
    int num = 10;

    for(int i=1; i<N; i=i+2) 
    {
       if(num%i==0)
        count++;
    }

    for(int i=2;i<N;i=i+2) 
    {
       if(num%i==0)
        count++;
    }
}
```

***In the main :***

```
int main()
{
    // Record start time
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Portion of code to be timed
    scenario1();
    // Record end time
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;

    cout << "Elapsed time for the 1st scenario is : " << elapsed.count() << " second." << endl;

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Portion of code to be timed
    scenario2();
    // Record end time
    finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    elapsed = finish - start;
    cout << "Elapsed time for the 2st scenario is : " << elapsed.count() << " second." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
Elapsed time for the 1st scenario is : 13.842 second.
Elapsed time for the 2st scenario is : 14.3887 second.
```

*So, it seems The first scenario has the better execution time...*

***Notice :*** that in smaller numbers it make no difference and its better using of one loop instead of two.